# What does 「おいちゃあ」 mean?

Tags: words

It is a situation which a salesperson announces to a group of people to attract them to buy his goods

Here is the full sentence.

> 品{しな}数{かず}すくないけど 種{しゅ}類{るい}に **おいちゃあ** そのへんのデパートなみだ!

What does おいちゃあ mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sentence is frank expression.
I think only veteran seller tends to use it.

In politely,

> 品数{しなかず}は少ないですが、種類{しゅるい}に**おいては**その辺{あたり}りのデパート並{な}みです。

So 「**おいちゃあ**」menas「**おいては**」.
And 「おいては」 is like 「ついては」.
I think it can be translated "about" in english.

> There are few stuffs, but we can competitive with near department
>   stores about a kind of stuffs.

If my explanation is bad, someone may correct it :)

Comment: I'd translate 「おいては」 to "when it comes to":

 We do not have many goods, but when it comes to variation, we're as good your average department store.

And yeah, 「おいっちゃあ」 is colloquial.